# Deduce that $\sum \frac {a_n}{r_n}$ diverges.

Tags: calculus, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_n>0$ and the series $\sum a_n$ converges. Put
$r_n=\sum_{n=m}^\infty a_n$.
Prove that $$\frac {a_m}{r_m}+\dots+\frac {a_n}{r_n}>1- \frac {r_n}{r_m},$$ if $m<n$, and deduce that $\sum \frac {a_n}{r_n}$ diverges.
My problem is to deduce that $\sum \frac {a_n}{r_n}$ diverges with $\frac {a_m}{r_m}+\dots+\frac {a_n}{r_n}>1- \frac {r_n}{r_m}$.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry,something is lost.Prove that am/rm+...+an/rn>1- rn/rm,if m<n, deduce that ∑(an/rn) diverges.

Comment: My problem is how to deduce that ∑(an/rn) diverges

Comment: Consider using the [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you know how to prove the inequality
$$\frac {a_m}{r_m}+\frac{a_{m+1}}{r_{m+1}}+\ldots+\frac {a_n}{r_n} > 1-\frac{r_{n}}{r_m}.$$
Now for any fixed $m$ the right-hand side of this inequality tends to $1$, which contradicts to [Cauchy's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_convergence_test).

Comment: Sorry,my question is how to deduce that $\sum \frac {a_n}{r_n}$ diverges.

Comment: @Curran, I edited my answer.

Comment: @ njguliyev, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

By the assumptions, $m<n$ implies $r_{m}>r_{n}$. Hence
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{a_{m}}{r_{m}}+\dots+\frac{a_{n}}{r_{n}} & > & \frac{1}{r_{m}}\left(a_{m}+\dots+a_{n}\right)\\
 & = & \frac{1}{r_{m}}\left(r_{m}-r_{n}+a_{n}\right)\\
 & > & \frac{1}{r_{m}}\left(r_{m}-r_{n}\right)\\
 & = & 1-\frac{r_{n}}{r_{m}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $n\rightarrow\infty$, then 
$$
\sum_{k=m}^{\infty}\frac{a_{k}}{r_{k}}\geq1-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{r_{n}}{r_{m}}=1,\forall m.
$$
This implies the partial sum sequence 
$$
b_{N}:=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{a_{k}}{r_{k}}
$$
is not Cauchy, and so $\sum\frac{a_{k}}{r_{k}}$ diverges.