# Is there a sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $\lim_n t_n < \infty$ and $\sup_n S_n < \infty$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Let $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $t_0 =0$. We define an induced sequence $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ by
$$
S_n := \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_i}.
$$

I would like to ask if there is a sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $\lim_n t_n < \infty$ and $\sup_n S_n < \infty$. Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **no**:

Let $T = \lim t_n$ and $u_n = \frac{t_n}{T} \to 1$

$$S_n \ge \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac1{1-u_i}\left(u_{i+1} - u_i\right)$$

Let $a_n = u_{n+1} - u_n$ and $R_n = \sum_{m=n}^{\infty} a_m = 1 - u_n$ it is clear that $\sum a_n$ converges. Using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/533006/468504) $\sum \frac{a_n}{R_n}$ diverges. This conclude the proof.

---

This proves that:

> If $(t_n)_n$ is an increasing sequence of real numbers and $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} t_n < \infty$ then, $$\sup_{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{t_{k+1} - t_k}{t_n - t_k} = \infty$$